# Using the new Relationships field for a conference site

Tags: relationships

I'm working with a client that uses EE to promote its annual conferences. Although I haven't used it yet, the Relationship field in EE 2.6.x seems like it would be perfect for what I have in mind, but I am hoping to get some advice on how to best set it up.

Each conference has a number of presentations, each of which has one or more presenters. I'm thinking the relationships would be organized like so:

- Conferences

  - Presentations

    - Presenters

Assuming that each of these are the names of my channels, how should I create the relationships between them? One relationship that links them all? One for Conferences and Presentations and another for Presentations and Presenters?

Any pointers on how to set this up would be greatly appreciated--thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like everything could be controlled from the middle of the relationship.

Inside your presentations channel field group, you would have a conferences relationship field linked to the conferences channel.  And also in that field group, you would have a relationship field to your presenters channel.  This leaves your conferences as the parent, which is what you would want since they would change with the least frequency.  That's how I've done it before myself, anyway, and it worked well.

Comment: Thank you, I think this will be quite useful. I've noticed, however, that the upgrade to EE 2.6.x seems to have broken the existing relationship field type that I had in place before, so I've got some work to do fixing that problem before I will be able to implement this suggestion.